Why is my function returning zero instead of a memory address?
I am learning c programming. Here is some sample code that I cannot seem to understand:
#include <stdio.h>

int* returnArray(){
    int arr[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    return arr;
}

int main(){
    printf("%x", returnArray());
}


If I run this code I get 0 printed out. If I redeclare my local variable in returnArray function as a static local variable, a memory address is printed out. Why do I need to declare the local variable as static before I can print out a hexadecimal memory address? Why am I getting 0 when I don't use static and what does getting zero mean in terms of what's going on under the hood?
Below is the code that prints out the memory address:
#include <stdio.h>

int* returnArray(){
    static int arr[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%x", returnArray());
    return 0;
}

Also, if I change the function return type and implement differently as below:
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int returnArray(){
    int arr[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%x", returnArray());
    return 0;
}

an actual memory address is returned. Why is that?

Note that all 3 major compilers show a warning by default (at least on their latest versions).

Maybe I missed something, but why are we writing 5 answers to a question that has probably already been asked 100+ times and has known canonical duplicates? Come on people.

Without using static, you're returning the address of a local variable with automatic storage duration from a function.  That variable's lifetime ends after the function returns, making the returned value indeterminate.
Accessing an indeterminate value, such as the address of a variable who's lifetime has ended, causes undefined behavior in your code, which in this case manifests as a value of 0.
This is spelled out in section 6.2.4p2 of the C standard:

If an object is referred to outside of its lifetime, the behavior is
undefined. The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the
object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.

Also, it's undefined behavior to print a pointer value using the %x format specifier, as that specifier expects an unsigned int.  You need to use the %p format specifier to print a pointer value, and you need to cast the pointer to void * (one of the few cases where such a cast is required).

Re "Without using static, you're returning the address of a local variable from a function.", With static, you're also returning the address of a local variable from a function. static doesn't affect the scope of the variable; it affects the lifetime the variable. (The rest of the answer is correct. Just the first sentence is wrong, or at least misleading.)

When you declare an array (or any other sort of variable), inside a function, without either the extern or static modifier, it has automatic storage duration, which means, among other things, that it's stored either in the function's "stack frame" or in CPU registers, and it only exists as long as the function is executing.
When you return the address of an array with automatic storage duration from the function where it's declared, what you have returned is a pointer to an array that no longer exists.  Pointers to data that no longer exists are said to have indeterminate values and you can't do anything with them.  You might have expected that you could still look at the numeric value of the pointer, and learn something about the computer's (virtual) memory layout, but the C standard says you can't even do that.  As quoted in another answer:

The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:

...
The value of a pointer to an object whose lifetime has ended is used


Emphasis mine: you cannot use, in any way, the value of a pointer to an object whose lifetime has ended, or your program has "undefined behavior" and the compiler is entitled to make it do whatever it wants.
Your compiler has elected to make returnArray return a null pointer, which (on almost all computers) prints as zero when reinterpreted as an integer by  printf("%x").1  This is a defensive measure that would make your program crash predictably if it tried to access the array that no longer exists, instead of producing garbage or otherwise malfunctioning unpredictably.  (Accessing the thing it points to is a subset of the possible ways to use a pointer.)
If you want to see the numeric value that the pointer had originally, you need to convert the pointer to an integer before you return it:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uintptr_t returnArray(void)
{
    int arr[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    return (uintptr_t) arr;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%#" PRIxPTR "\n", returnArray());
    return 0;
}

This program has unspecified behavior, which means the C standard doesn't say what number is printed, but it's guaranteed to print some number, and that number is guaranteed to be different from the number that would have been printed if you changed return (uintptr_t)arr to return (uintptr_t)(void *)0.2
Your second version of your program (returning arr as unsigned int with no explicit casts) effectively does the same thing -- convert the pointer to an integer before returning it -- except that, because on most current generation computers unsigned int is not as big as a pointer, it is probably chopping off the top half of the pointer's value.  On the computer I'm typing this on, my sample program prints a number like 0x7fffd4fe5700, and your version would probably print a number like 0xd4fe5700 instead.
(Also, officially you're not allowed to convert a pointer to an integer without an explicit cast, but most C compilers will wave that on through with at most a warning, for backward compatibility with very old code.)

1 Technically, printf("%x", pointer) with no explicit casts also has undefined behavior, but as long as the compiler doesn't decide that the undefined behavior means it doesn't have to actually emit a call to printf, it's very likely to behave the same as if you'd written printf("%x", (unsigned int)pointer).  As discussed above this means it would probably only print part of the pointer's value.
2 Technically, (uintptr_t)(void *)0; might not evaluate to the same number as (uintptr_t)0; but the last time I tripped over a computer that actually did that was more than thirty years ago.

Your first snippet has two errors:

You are using a pointer to an object that no longer exists.
You are incorrectly using printf.

Both of these result in undefined behaviour.
Objects with automatic storage duration (like most local variables, including your non-static arrays) cease to exist once the block/function to which they belong is exited. Using static extends its lifetime beyond the end of the function call.
printf( "%p\n", (void*)... ) is the correct way to print a pointer.
Fixed:
#include <stdio.h>

int *returnArray( void ) {
   static int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
   return arr;
}

int main( void ) {
   printf( "%p\n", (void*)returnArray() );
}

Example output:
0x404020

Demo on Compiler Explorer.

If the address of an object is taken and then the object's lifetime ends, the Standard treats all copies of that address as indeterminate.  Since the compiler can see that array object's lifetime ends between the time its address is taken (via array decay) and the time code attempts to output the value of the pointer, it has no obligation to actually form the address of the array.  Indeed, it's likely that a compiler could realize that nothing will be done with the array within its lifetime, and the compiler could thus decide not to even bother creating it.
Note that situation would have been slightly different if e.g. the function had returned a uintptr_t rather than a pointer, since any conversion of a valid pointer to a uintptr_t will always yield some particular number.  While any special meaning that number had during the pointer's useful lifetime will disappear when the pointer becomes indeterminate, any numerical traits that it had (e.g. it happened to be a non-zero multiple of 123456) will be unaffected.  On the other hand, I still don't think the Standard would have imposed any restrictions upon the particular value yielded by such a pointer-to-integer conversion other than that it not equal (uintptr_t)(void*)0.

You're trying to use the value of a pointer to an object whose lifetime has ended. That's undefined behavior:

The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:

...
The value of a pointer to an object whose lifetime has ended is used
...


You're also using an invalid format specifier - %x takes an unsigned int.
